# read, write Map to editable text file - java, eclipse, android

Tags: java

I am new to Android development using eclipse, although not new to software development in general.

I would like to use a Java Map to hold string key-value pairs and read and write this map to an editable text file in the application's default directory. I have been searching all over, found pieces, but have trouble putting it all together.

I think there are basically 2 parts to this task:

1) Create a string, string Map with key-value pairs in my program – okay this is pretty easy.

2) Read and write the Map to an editable text file in the Android application's default directory. This should be easy, but I have not found a solution anywhere. I would think there would be a map.readAsText function and map.writeAsText function somewhere. I think this is basically what I need.

Can someone help me out – point me in the right direction?
Thank you very much.

Comment: No, those functions you mention do not exist. But you can iterate your map elements and write them to a file using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java [`Properties` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is a serializable Map with a simple, human-editor-friendly format (see the [Java Tutorial: Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).  For example:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("name", "Charles");
p.put("age", "45");
p.list(System.out); // new FileOutputStream("properties.txt")
// name=Charles
// age=45
p.load(new FileInputStream("properties.txt"));
```

Comment: Thank you! The file "properties.txt" will be created in the default application directory?

Comment: @user1247254: if you don't supply a path with the filename it will be located in the "current working directory" (i.e. `System.getProperty("user.dir")`), I'm not sure where this would be in Android.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to save to file are key-value I would consider using [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) for this.

You can convert from Properties to Map like this:

```
 Properties p = new Properties();
   Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> set = map.entrySet();
   for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : set) {
     p.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }
```